# Add External Function In Html Editor JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I Am Creating Application To Html Builder I Want To Add More Function in HTML Editor.

Can We Add External Function in HTML Editor. Means in There Default Function is "Text indent", "Text alignment" etc... Are also Available...

But.

Can we add More Function(Controls) Like as Input box, Button, Checkbox ?